# Xively extract current datastream value

Tags: python, python-2.7, xively

I'm able to extract the latest value of the datastream using the following code **BUT the problem is that if I change the value or update the value at the Xively dashboard console then the code isn't able to capture the change but still remains displaying the old value!**

```
# main program entry point - runs continuously updating our datastream with the
def run():
  print "Starting Xively tutorial script"

  feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)

  datastream = get_datastream(feed)
  datastream.max_value = None
  datastream.min_value = None

  while True:

    if DEBUG:
      print "Updating Xively feed with value: %s" 
      datastream.at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      datastream.update() 
      check_point = datastream.current_value
      print "AAGYa: %s" % check_point
      if check_point == '50':
         outPin = file("/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value", "w")
         outPin.write("1")
      elif check_point == '':
         outPin = file("/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value", "w")
         outPin.write("1")
      elif check_point == '':
         outPin = file("/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value", "w")
         outPin.write("1")

run()
```

Here's the get_datastream():

```
# function to return a datastream object. This either creates a new datastream,
# or returns an existing one
def get_datastream(feed):
  try:
    datastream = feed.datastreams.get("load_avg")
    if DEBUG:
      print "Found existing datastream"
    return datastream
  except:
    if DEBUG:
      print "Creating new datastream"
    datastream = feed.datastreams.create("load_avg", tags="load_01")
    return datastream
```

Comment: You forgot to post the definition of `get_datastream()` method...

Comment: It looks like you have modified an example script, but it doesn't work. You should instead write from scratch, and if you are in doubt, just post the initial problem you want to solve and it will be easier to help. For example: _"I want to read data from a Xively feed and set GPIO pins accordingly. I would like to use 3 pins which represent red, green and blue LEDs. I also have a button that I wish to be an input to Xively channel."_

Comment: No It's not like that THE THING is working the code is all working the only fact is that I need to restart the script if I make any changes to the xively dashboard where the value is returned/posted so that this change is read by the script or else the script keeps on getting the old value

Comment: Also I added the get_datastream() def..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `get_datastream()` outside the loop.

Comment: Sorry to waste your and my time was so simple do not know where my mind was